# Error message in Stata: Cannot compute an improvement -- discontinuous region encountered (for panel ordered logit/probit model)

Tags: stata

I have panel data for OECD countries between the years 2010 and 2021. I use stata 14.

I categorize GINI into 4 groups as follows

[image]

This is named as d_gini, which is my dependent variable. And I apply the panel data ordered probit model. I regress it on World Pandemic Discussion Index (WPDI) as follows:

[image]

But, regardless of probit or logit model, I encounter with this error. How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Note: When I try this panel ordered logit regression with different explanatory variable, for example I use log_GDP in stead of WPDI, this regression works. I don't see any error. However, I need to use this explanatory variable WPDI. How can I fix?

Comment: You’re throwing away useful information. Treat Gini as a bounded continuous outcome: logit link, binomial family, robust standard errors.